# Party Wall Act - unclear interpretation of party fence wall definition?

Tags: england-and-wales, statutory-construction, interpretation

I'm looking at sections 1(1)(b) and 20 of the Party Wall Act, and they just don't make sense to me, definitionally.

## Problem #1: s.20 seems to provide an impossible or meaningless definition

> **s.20:** “party fence wall” means a wall (not being part of a building) which stands on lands of different owners and is used or constructed to be used for separating such adjoining lands, but does not include a wall constructed on the land of one owner the artificially formed support of which projects into the land of another owner

The phrase excluding *"a wall constructed on the land of one owner the artificially formed support of which projects into the land of another owner"* could be read ambiguously.

- IT EITHER MEANS: "a wall constructed *entirely* on the land of one owner (A), the artificially formed support of which projects into the land of another owner (B)";
- OR IT MEANS: "a wall constructed *partly - but **not** entirely -* on the land of one owner (A), the artificially formed support of which projects into the land of another owner (B)"

The problem is, **both** of these are problematic, whichever is chosen.

- If the first interpretation is correct, then the wall being excluded cannot ever have been a candidate party fence wall in the first place, because to even consider it as a party fence wall, the wall must stand on more than one person's land ("a party fence wall means a wall .. which stands on lands of different owners..."). ***No* walls will ever be excluded if the first interpretation is correct**. The clause would be meaningless.
- If the second interpretation is correct, then we have the opposite problem. If it is intended to signify a wall constructed in part but *not* entirely on (A)'s land, then basic wall construction dictates that the wall's support will *always* project into another owner (B)'s land, because walls are supported under their full width. ***Every* wall that could be a party fence wall will be excluded if the second interpretation is correct.** The definition wouldn't cover any walls at all.

This is a quick sketch of the 3 ways a wall could be placed and supported near a boundary:

[image]

- Layouts #2 and #3 aren't party fence walls because the wall itself is completely within the property boundary of B, so it doesn't "stand on lands of different owners".
- Layout #1 *can* be a party fence wall, - but only if the exclusion clause has an ineffective/nullifying interpretation: "_a wall built on *just one owner's land entirely/exclusively/only*". If that's correct then no wall that looks like layout #1 ever gets excluded, so Layout #1 will always be deemed a party fence wall. (If we had made the alternative assumption, that it means "built partly but not entirely on an owner (A)'s land" then the Layout #1 wall is clearly built partly on (A)'s land and its support clearly projects into another owner (B)'s land, so Layout #1 could never be a party fence wall. In which case nothing could.)

What approach to reading the exclusion clause wording would allow it to have a sensible meaning, which presumably should exclude some walls but not others?

*Note: I'm asking about the meaning in law of the legislative wording, rather than "what it might be believed or assumed to mean", as these could be completely different.*

Comment: Could it be clarifying that, if the wall (excluding the support) is on one person's property, and the support crosses into another person's property, that's not a party wall? Otherwise, one might assume that this is a party wall, not realising that the support doesn't count as part of the wall.

Comment: That would exactly repeat the first clause which says a party fence wall _stands on lands of different owners_. Legislation pretty much never repeats itself for emphasis within a single-sentence definition. If that was the aim, they'd say something like: _"... and a wall standing entirely within the property of a single owner, shall not be deemed a party fence wall by reason of a projection of its artificial support only, onto the land of another owner."_ (nb for clarity, a "Party wall" is not the same as a "Party fence wall")

Answer (score 3):

The phrase in question is clarifying that if the wall (excluding the support) is on one person's property, and the support crosses into another person's property, then it is not a party fence wall.

Why make this clarification, given that if a wall doesn't stand "on lands of different owners", it can't be a party wall anyway?

[Architect's Legal Handbook: The Law for Architects](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_RmoBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA226&lpg=PA226&dq=uk%20%20%22party%20fence%20wall%22%20%22artificially%20formed%20support%22&source=bl&ots=C-OxfjYmOm&sig=DGgM0fFKOQ6IkOCOpSIgxu_Pe_0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGwrPg4_PaAhWpsaQKHTkGDIAQ6AEIYjAJ#v=onepage&q=uk%20%20%22party%20fence%20wall%22%20%22artificially%20formed%20support%22&f=false) suggests that this is because there is a different rule for walls which separate buildings, hence the need to highlight the difference (emphasis mine):

> ...rights of adjoining owners do not arise where only the foundations project on the to the adjoining land if the wall concerned is a boundary wall, not being part of a building, **but they do arise if such a wall separates buildings belonging to different owners**.

Comment: This sounds promising. But I can't visualise an example from your brief quote. Could you add a simple example to the answer, so I can see the point it's getting at?

Comment: I'm no expert, but my understanding is that if you have a wall like in Layout #2 above (wall on property A, support on both A and B): if it's a wall separating buildings, it's a party wall, and so the owners of both A and B may have certain rights and responsibilities; but if it's a wall separating land, it's not a party (fence) wall, so it's entirely the responsibility of B.